# Python Selenium webDrvierWati not useful in multiple thread

Tags: python, selenium

I am selenium rookie.

I have a question.

I using threads simulate 10 users

Sometime the first chromedriver (thread No.1)

But second chromedriver (thread 2,3...10) click no yet

Other chromedriver was affected by the first page

Report an error

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div"}

Other chromedrivers that have not clicked button 1 went directly to this line

WebDriverWait(driver,30,1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div')))

so make it timeOutReport

How can fix it.

English is not my native language. so I didn't explain clearly enough I’m awfully sorry.

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import threading

def selenium_mult():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
    ser=Service('./chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = ser,options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_window_size(540,480)
    driver.get('https:/website') 

    WebDriverWait(driver,10,1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[3]/button[1]'))) 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[3]/button[1]').click()  #click button 1
    Ftime = datetime.now()

    WebDriverWait(driver,30,1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div'))) 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div').click() #click button 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=selenium_mult)
        t.start()
```

I found that the part of clicking the button is not working I try to insert print("click") between webDriverWait and click It response 10 times for me but some webdriver not work

Answer (score 0):

I found that the part of clicking the button is not working
I try to insert print("click") between webDriverWait and click
It response 10 times for me but some webdriver not work

Comment: If this is a new finding describing the steps you've performed to solve your problem, please just add it tot he question.